# C#: How can I instantiate a List of private inner class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

everybody. I'm doing unit-testing now, while I have a problem I can not solve it by my own. 
The problem is listed below:

```
public class A {
    private class B{ }
    private List<B> list = new List<B>;
}
```

I want to test whether `list[i]` is `null` or not? Now I can use Reflection to get the list, But the question is how can I add a instance of `B` into the list? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not your job to test the C# compiler. This list will never be `null` in a scope that's accessible during runtime. Please show a representative example of your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, just testing this piece of code is not productive.
While i disagree with the other answer you got re: not testing privates, the test should be meaningful to the behaviour.

Sure, you can write unit tests for each member being there making refactoring of any sort a major PIB. Would this be productive? not really.

But, for what it's worth, you just need a little more reflection magic and voila:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void PrivateListCanHaveObjectsAdded()
    {
      var target = new A();

      var b = typeof(A).GetNestedType("B", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
      var list = typeof(A).GetField("list", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

      var bInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(b);
      var addMethod = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(b).GetMethod("Add");
      var countProperty = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(b).GetProperty("Count");
      addMethod.Invoke(list.GetValue(target), new object[] { bInstance });

      Assert.AreEqual(1, countProperty.GetValue(list.GetValue(target)));
    }
```

Comment: If the answer works for you, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 3):

Unit tests are meant to test ... units. They're not meant to test the nitty-gritty `private` internal workings of your program. They're intended to test the `public` facing API of your classes.

If the public methods of your classes work, then you know any `private` mechanisms they depend on also work. If the `private` mechanisms break, they'll cause a public method to stop working.

Comment: You can call them `test whatever` or you can call them `unit tests`. `Tests whatever` exist to ensure that nobody modified the code file in such a way that would break the expected behaviour (whether public or private) without KNOWING about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But if a public method crashes, the reason for that crash could not only be the private internal mechanisms, it maybe something else executed after this private thing, which means that I have to make sure the private thing in my test correct, after that, I can test the other thing....?